# How can I copy a file from Linux to Windows using ssh commands

Tags: linux, ssh

I have a ftp server on my Windows server and a Linux VM running on hyper-v, as a part of automation I need to copy a file from Linux to Windows and do some other task using the information from the Linux VM.

Either I have to create a file directly on the ftp server running on Windows or copy that file from the VM using the Linux commands.
I tried to copy the file using SSH, but how do I supply password?

```
echo 'Some Text' | ssh user@remotehost "cat > /remotefile.txt"
```

Comment: "how do i supply password?" you can use public key authentication

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `sshpass`:

```
sshpass -p 'you_pass' scp your_file user@remotehost:/path/to/dest
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `expect` to pass the password.

A very good example can be found at https://bash.cyberciti.biz/security/expect-ssh-login-script/

More information regarding the `expect` command can be found at http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect

Answer (score -4):

Thanks for the reply.
I got my answer using the curl command

```
curl -T /home/vyatta/suresh/suresh.test ftp://192.168.1.*/
```

this worked for me

Comment: What has that to do with the question **as asked**?  If you wanted to know how to automate moving a file from a Linux to a Windows box, you should have asked that question instead.